# How to disable Pinned TaskPane when clicked MailItem from Archive Folder

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have enabled the SupportsPinning in Manifest and also implemented event handler of ItemChanged. It works prefect until one of our users, pinned the taskPane and search email item with "All Mailboxes".

[Steps to reproduce]

1. Click any email item in Inbox
2. Activate the Addin
3. Pinned the Addin
4. Search something with "All mailBoxes"
5. Got some results which emails are locating in Archive MailBox
6. click to the email which it is located in Archive MailBox
7. ItemChanged event fired from last selected email
8. TaskPane looks like unload and reload
9. Office.Initialize will not be fired, but general JQuery could be fired.
10. None of the any Office API will be executed
11. Select other email which it is located in Inbox
12. no change on TaskPane, ItemChanged would fire
13. Addin only works normal if I close and re-activate the addin

After some searching and read carefully, I found that mail items in Archive Mailbox is not supported to activate the addin. If I click any email item outside of the "Search results", the addin button won't be available. But as of the Pinned feature, now we could have a way to be "activated" the addin from not supported mail item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#mailbox-items-available-to-add-ins

is there a way to "Force" disable the activation or "force" close the addin when user selected any "non-supported" email item?

Comment: anyone from Microsoft could answer or follow?

Comment: If a pinned taskpane is open while an unsupported mail is selected, it should either display an error or close while that folder is displayed. To help me repro the bug, how are you creating the "Archive Mailbox" is it a offline PST file?